# import Visual studio 2005 in the 2008

Tags: vb.net

I am working on the visual studio.net 2008 but I have a web application in the visual studio 2005. I want to open this application in the visual studio 2008 but show the some error in the web.config.
              Please help me how to imports this applications.

I want to import vb.net 2005 into the vb.net 2008

Comment: Please provide more information. What error for example

Comment: It would be better if you provide the exact error that you are encountering.

Comment: And the error is...vote to close?

Answer (score 1):

Just try and open the VS 2005 project in VS 2008. This should start the [Visual Studio Conversion Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60z6y467%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that should assist you in upgrading your project from VS 2005 to VS 2008.

If the conversion encounters any errors the Wizard would end up showing a page inside Visual Studio which would enlist all the issues encountered while upgrade.

If you still encounter any problem running your application please post the exact error message with the code snippet causing the error and we would then be able to assist you further.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The upgrade wizard is only for vb 6.0 convert into visual stdio 2008